Looking for correct DAX Formula - Sum Values in Column
I am trying to come up with a chart in power bi, to project how much work we are expecting on a given day. I have 5 columns namely:

Current Workable (work available today, Day 1)
Recovery (work in transit to reach factory on a date)
Pack Commit (factory capacity to finish work on a date)
Projected Workable (Column which needs help)
Index (starts at 0)

I plan to use the values from Projected Workable column on y-axis and dates on x-axis. However, I am unable to come up with a formula to show the correct value on a given date for Projected Workable. In simple words:

When Index = 0, Projected Workable (Index 0) = Current Workable +
Recovery
When Index = 1, Projected Workable (Index 1) = Projected
Workable (Index 0) + Recovery (Index 1) - Pack Commit (Index 0)
When Index = 2, Projected Workable (Index 2) = Projected Workable (Index
1)+ Recovery (Index 2) - Pack Commit (Index 1)

So on..
Extra notes:
When Projected Workable is less than capacity (6000), we can only Pack Commit to work that we have (not more).
We do not work on weekends or off days.
Current formula I have written so far, (it is wrong):
Projected Workable = IF('Workable'[Index] = 0,'Workable'[Current Workable]+'Workable'[Recovery],('Workable'[Current Workable]-IF(('Workable'[Day of Week Name]="Saturday")||('Workable'[Day of Week Name]="Sunday")||('Workable'[Date] = 'Workable'[Off Days]),0,'Workable'[Pack Commit])+'Workable'[Recovery]))

I was expecting it to work as if Projected Workable gets reduced by how much ever Pack Commit and the Recovery gets added to Projected Workable, and next day Pack Commit gets deducted from leftover Workable from previous day and Recovery gets added (if any), so on.
In the screenshot the correct Projected Workable for Index 1 should have been 14447 + 20294 - 6000 = 28741.
But I cannot seem to refer to the previous cell on the same column and am stuck here.
Use the below snippet to see a sample table, this was the only way I could share a table. (better than just a screenshot)


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Index</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Day of Week Name</td>
      <td>Current Workable</td>
      <td>Pack Commit</td>
      <td>Recovery</td>
      <td>Projected Workable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>4/9/2024</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>14194</td>
      <td>6000</td>
      <td>253</td>
      <td>14447</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4/10/2024</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>6000</td>
      <td>20294</td>
      <td>14294</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4/11/2024</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>6000</td>
      <td>1324</td>
      <td>-4676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4/12/2024</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>6000</td>
      <td>1627</td>
      <td>-4373</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4/13/2024</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4/14/2024</td>
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>





Don't post your code as  an image. Please share some input data

Added a code snippet to run, that should output a sample table to assist.
